# Ubuntu run script as user when usb inserted

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, udev

I want to automatically attach any inserted usb drive to a virtual machine that is run inside ubuntu under particular user login.

To do that, I've set up the following udev rule(from [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177897/run-a-script-that-displays-an-x-window-from-an-udev-rule), [[2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229987/udev-rule-to-match-any-usb-storage-device)):

```
KERNEL=="sd?", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/bin/su me -c '/home/me/automout.sh'"
```

To test udev working, the `automount.sh` script was done as following:

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "$devpath">/home/me/2
```

When run manually, the empty file is created inside home, but when a usb is inserted, nothing happens. What may be the cause of that?

Comment: It looks like a permissions problem. What if you write the file to a folder w 777 permissions that is owned by root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as MiiinimalLogic suggested, the problem was owner of the script.
If you want to run a script as another user via `su`, the script should belong to root.

The file may still reside in user's home.